# Issues with Hibernate Validator after upgrading from Hibernate 3 to 4 with Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

Issues with Hibernate Validator after upgrading from Hibernate 3 to 4 with Spring 4

I took over a very old Java project (rich client, swing, hibernate 3) which has some sort of homegrown Dependency Injection, uses Hibernate 3 and it has *manual transaction management*. Meaning every freakin DAO method gets a boolean that triggers a session to be opened or not. You can imagine what this means when you touch that fragile construct on many places... Anyhow, I am not here to whine...here's my Problem:

I have to implement a new complex feature and soon had to realize that this whole manual transaction thing gets out of control and I could convince the customer to refactor the whole thing to use Spring transaction mgmt in combination with hibernate 4.

So I started to implement this and after some major issues I came accross, the whole thing now runs but with some more detailed hickups.

One that drives me nuts is *Hibernate Validator*. The existing implementation is the old fashioned way I guess. All Entity Classes derive from a class named DomainObject which contains a `org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator` for all Entities that are existing in the project.
In the entities themselves this validator will be called with .InvalidValues() to verify the fields.

Since I upgraded to Hibernate-Core 4.3.6.Final with Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE I get a lot of issues when Entities are to be validated. I know I am using an old Validator Version but when I upgrade to a higher one, the whole project has countless errors like `The type org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` but I wasn't able to resolve this with all answers I found on SO for it.

Right now the validation which causes errors runs in a `SwingWorker Thread` and while debugging it I can see the exception is swallowed somewhere deep in Spring and I don't even get a stacktrace :-(
I assume the issues still comes from a bad combination of the hibernate dependencies but I was really desperate until I got something that work together which
you can see in the pom.xml snippet below.

Here the snippets

```
<!-- Hibernate Stuff -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    <!-- Hibernate Core needs a higher version so we exclude this one -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.6.10.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>javassist</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.12.0.GA</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>c3p0</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>0.9.1.2</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
```

This is the method in all Entities that will be called during validation.

```
 /**
 * validate the entity. This method will be called internally before save or
 * update to check validity before sql statements
 */
@Override
@Transient
protected InvalidValue[] validate(final String fieldName) {
    if (fieldName == null) {
        return VALIDATOR_ASSEMBLY_ENTRY.getInvalidValues(this);
    } else {
        return VALIDATOR_ASSEMBLY_ENTRY.getInvalidValues(this, fieldName);
    }
}
```

Any hints ? If you need more Code, tell me. The whole Spring and Hibernate config is done in Java. No xml.

Comment: `InvalidValue` doesn't exist in Hibernate Validator 4 and later, i.e. you'd have to adapt "the method in all Entities that will be called during validation" so it's using the current version of Hibernate Validator (or actually Bean Validation, which is the spec implemented by Hibernate Validator beginning with version 4).

Comment: @Gunnar yeah that is what I expected. So I started (just to see if it helps) to deactivate every single validate method in all entities, and voila...now those strange errors are gone. But to really implement Hibernate Validation the annotation driven way with version 4 will take me some more time :-/ . Do you know a good tutorial on best practices using hibernate validator 4 with spring ?

Comment: to give others some who reach this question a hint:  I now finished the new implementation of H-V and a good guidance was [This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-composition) and [that](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-obtaining-validator) .
Basically the implementations of H-V 3 and 4 are not that different. I just didn't see that all the custom validators were the parts that drove me nuts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I fix this with a little workaround. Put this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for your Answer @KimTiagoBaptista . Actually not the dependency, but the implementation was the issue. E.G. that the validate method of H-V4 returns a set of `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>` instead of an array of `org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue` in H-V3, but it does the same in terms of context. The more nagging things were, that H-V4 caused some strange issues with spring transaction management, but that is another long story.